# How to convert struct type into separate columns in SQL using pyspark?

Tags: sql, json, struct

I have a column named filters which has the value like this:

```
{
    "key": "filters",
    "location": null, 
    "value": "{\"shipment\":[],\"load\":[],\"purchase\":[],\"department\":[],\"vendor\":[1983852],\"tmLoc\":[],\"inYardGoalDate\":\"2023-08-12\"}"
}
```

I need to split these key-value pairs into multiple columns. I have tried `JSON_TUPLE` which returns the value in this format : `'[]'`

My database is throwing an error if I try `JSON_Extract`, `char_index`.

How to convert it into string format in multiple columns?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: your tag is incorrect